# SUMIFS function returns Zero value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

The SUMIFS function return zero value since one of the parameters do not exist for a specific value.

How can I modify the function so when it will not encounter one of the parameters, it will not return zero value but just refer to the parameters that do exist.

```
=SUMIFS('GL Account Details'!$AB:$AB,'GL Account Details'!$N:$N,Sheet3!A4,'GL Account Details'!$A:$A,Sheet3!$H$1,'GL Account Details'!$A:$A,Sheet3!$H$2)
```

The parameter "Sheet3!$H$2" do not exist for the specific value "Sheet3!A4". For different values the "Sheet3!$H$2" will be relevant

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, that [SUMIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-C9E748F5-7EA7-455D-9406-611CEBCE642B) formula will never produce anything but zero unless Sheet3!H1 and Sheet3!H2 are the same value. If they are different then the value in 'GL Account Details'!A:A cannot be both at the same time; since you can never make a match, you never get anything but zero.

You can introduce an **OR** statement into the [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-C9E748F5-7EA7-455D-9406-611CEBCE642B) by wrapping it in a [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff).

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS('GL Account Details'!$AB:$AB,
                   'GL Account Details'!$A:$A, Sheet3!$H$1:$H$2,
                   'GL Account Details'!$N:$N, Sheet3!A4))
```

[image: Sumproduct_sumifs_GL]

Alternately, you can simply add two SUMIFS together.

```
=SUM(SUMIFS('GL Account Details'!$AB:$AB,
            'GL Account Details'!$A:$A, Sheet3!$H$1,
            'GL Account Details'!$N:$N, Sheet3!A4)),
     SUMIFS('GL Account Details'!$AB:$AB,
            'GL Account Details'!$A:$A, Sheet3!$H$2))
```

Comment: thanks Jeeped! its ok now after using two SUMIFS together